# Where does kivy.storage.jsonstore saves its files?

Tags: python, json, kivy

I have a kivy app, where I use JsonStorage. Where does kivy save the json files, so how can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the json file is on the same level as the `kivy_venv` folder